# How to specify a whitelist of the metrics I want to use in spring-boot with micrometer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-micrometer

We want to use only some of the given metrics from micrometer in our spring-boot application. We find the following code-snippet in the docs. This should disable all metrics by default and should enable us to create a whitelist of possible metrics.

[Spring blog about Micrometer metrics](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector)

```
management.metrics.enable.root=false
management.metrics.enable.jvm=true
```

The problem is, that it doesn't work. All existing metrics are written to our graphite instance.

We found already a workaround but we would like to edit our metrics in our property files.

This is our current workaround:

```
@Configuration
public class MicrometerGraphiteConfig {

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> commonTags() {
        return registry -> registry
            .config()
            .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyUnless(this::isMetricToInclude))
            .commonTags("a_tag", "some_common_tags");
    }

    private boolean isMetricToInclude(Meter.Id id) {
        return id.getName().startsWith("jvm.");
    }
}
```

Do anyone has any experience to share, what we have to think of to reach this goal within the property-file configuration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `management.metrics.enable.all=false` not `management.metrics.enable.root=false` as that property has been removed.
I had the same requirement to whitelist the metrics and just choose the required ones. The blog post is out of date and was advised to use `management.metrics.enable.all=false` by the Spring Boot devs on gitter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try that solution and let you know.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cb2 can you share a link of the Blog Post which shows how we can expose only a specific list of metrics that we want (something like whitelisting)?

Comment: @sem10 blog is linked in original question but here is the relevant section: [meter-filters](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector#meter-filters)

Comment: So if `management.metrics.enable.all=false` the use code to whitelist specific ones  above will still work?