# How to remove the default core metrics from spring boot metrics (datadog)?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to disable all builtin metrics (jvm, cpu, etc) but keep my custom metrics.

When I enabled Spring Boot Actuator metrics together with Datadog I end up with +320 metrics sent to datadog. Most of these metrics are from the [builtin core metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-meter) (JVM metrics, CPU metrics, File description metrics) only 5 of those metrics are my custom metrics that are the ones that I want to send to datadog.

According to [this section of the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-getting-started):

> Spring Boot also configures built-in instrumentation (i.e. MeterBinder
>   implementations) that **you can control via configuration or dedicated
>   annotation markers**

but there is no direct example on how to exclude the those metrics

From what I found in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422023/how-to-specify-a-whitelist-of-the-metrics-i-want-to-use-in-spring-boot-with-micr) one way to control it is:

```
management.metrics.enable.all=false
management.metrics.enable.jvm=true
```

and that removes all the metrics except the JVM ones. But it **also removes my custom metrics**.

I don't see how can I reenable my custom metrics.

Just for the record the way I register the custom metrics is this way:

```
    @Autowired
    public void setMeterRegistry(MeterRegistry registry) {
        this.meterRegistry = registry;
    }

    ....
    Counter n_event_in = this.meterRegistry.counter("n_events_in");
```

This works ok, as long as `management.metrics.enable.all=true

So how can I disable all core metrics , but keep my custom metrics?

Comment: Please walk me through how to enable actuator metrics together with datadog and get it on UI? I am getting exceptions like `text cannot be parsed to duration` inspite of giving proper seconds value in step. Or with another way, I get datadog missing exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your metrics should have a common prefix like `myapp.metric1`, `myapp.metric2`, etc. 
Then you can disable all metrics and enable explicitly all `myapp.*` metrics like so:

application.properties:

```
management.metrics.enable.all=false
management.metrics.enable.myapp=true
```

the `management.metrics.enable.<your_custom_prefix>` will enable all `<your_custome_prefix>.*` metrics.

If you want to enable some of the built-in core metrics again, for example reenabling `jvm.*`, you can do:

```
management.metrics.enable.all=false
management.metrics.enable.myapp=true
management.metrics.enable.jvm=true
```

I've created a sample project [in github](https://github.com/ecerulm/spring-boot-app-with-metrics) that disables core metrics, enables custom metrics, and `jvm.*` metrics and sends to Datadog.